Take a backup from specific range
I need to backup the data of a specific table by week and then restore it but without truncate table . This table contains the fechaRegistro
I prepared the following script but I'm not sure about the way to declare date variables, could you help me about it, please?
#!/bin/bash
# VARIABLES
FECHA=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
SERVIDOR="$(hostname)"
PASSWORD='PASSWORD'
BD=ordenes
TABLA="backlogPedidos"
ARCHIVO="$SERVIDOR-${BD^^}${TABLA^^}-$FECHA.sql"
RUTA_NAS="/tmp/"


# Establecer variables para calcular el rango semanal
INICIO_SEMANA=$(date -d "last sunday - 6 days" +"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")
FIN_SEMANA=$(date -d "last saturday" +"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")

# Se generar el backup por rangoo de una semana
mysqldump --databases $BD --tables $TABLA --where="fechaRegistro BETWEEN '$INICIO_SEMANA' AND '$FIN_SEMANA'" --skip-comments --compact --single-transaction --default-character-set=UTF8 --insert-ignore --complete-insert --skip-triggers --skip-routines --no-create-info --disable-keys --set-gtid-purged=OFF -q --lock-tables=false --user=backup -p$PASSWORD > /tmp/$ARCHIVO

echo "Backup semanal generado: $ARCHIVO"


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648762/how-to-find-out-the-date-of-the-last-saturday-in-linux-shell-script-or-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015546/how-do-i-get-last-sunday-date-from-a-given-date-in-unix


I need to backup the data of a specific table by week and then restore
it but without truncate table

If we are talking about previous week based on current date then to find the starting day(Monday) use,
ebasha:~ # date --date="last monday - 7 days" +%Y-%m-%d
2024-11-18

End the previous week(Sunday)
ebasha:~ # date --date="last sunday" +%Y-%m-%d
2024-11-24


I created an example.
Change/add variables to the script and  commands to the dump as per your needs, the following is just a demostration
The file /etc/db_connect.conf contains db credentials such as:
DB_USER="user"
DB_PASSWORD="password"
DB_NAME="dbName"

Give proper permissions to the script and db ccredentials , in my case:
ebasha:~ # chmod 600 /etc/db_connect.conf
ebasha:~ # chmod 600 /root/backupTable.sh

Script,
#!/bin/bash

#db credentials
source /etc/db_connect.conf

TABLE_NAME="admin_login_log"
DATE_COLUMN="last_login_date"
BACKUP_DIR="/root/backup"
BACKUP_FILE="${BACKUP_DIR}/${TABLE_NAME}_backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql"

# start and end date of the previous week
START_DATE=$(date --date="last monday - 7 days" +%Y-%m-%d)" 00:00:00"
END_DATE=$(date --date="last sunday" +%Y-%m-%d)" 23:59:59"

# ensure the backup directory exists
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR"

# Perform the backup
mysqldump -u "$DB_USER" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" "$DB_NAME" "$TABLE_NAME" --where="$DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN '$START_DATE' AND '$END_DATE'" > "$BACKUP_FILE"

# Check if the backup was successful
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Backup successful: $BACKUP_FILE"
else
    echo "Backup failed."
    exit 1
fi

After executing
ebasha:~ # bash /root/backupTable.sh
Backup successful: /root/backup/admin_login_log_backup_2024-11-27.sql

